# django : Update two models using same API call

Tags: django, django-models

I have an API call which gets and receives the user data,
User model looks something like this -

I have a model for user -

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "name": "fname",
    "height": null,
    "weight": "59",
    "blood_pressure": "131",
    "blood_sugar": "320",
    "email": "m@gmail.com",
}
```

I want to save this data to be saved in `UserBody` model -

```
"height": null,
"weight": "59",
"blood_pressure": "131",
"blood_sugar": "320",
```

while I want rest of the data(id, name, email) to be saved in `BodyModel`

My `User` model looks like this -

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, blank=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=false, null=false)
    weight = models.IntegerField(blank=true, null=false)
    blood_pressure = models.IntegerField(blank=true, null=false)
    blood_sugar = models.IntegerField(blank=true, null=false)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=63, blank=True)
```

Class `UserBody` -

```
class UserBody(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionMixin):
        user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        height = models.IntegerField(blank=false, null=false)
        weight = models.IntegerField(blank=true, null=false)
        blood_pressure = models.IntegerField(blank=true, null=false)
        blood_sugar = models.IntegerField(blank=true, null=false)
```

I fiddled with making the `user` object `foreignKey` but I just can't wrap my head around how it should have worked. I have a `MyUser` serializer, but **I just don't know how to write a serializer for `UserBody` model**.
Help me with any direction, I will take it forward from there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't inherit your both models from AbstractBaseUser to prevent the duplication of your data (both models will have the same fields in this case, for example, 'password', 'groups', etc). Also you shouldn't define the same fields, such as 'height', 'weight', etc in both models for the same reasons - it's not a DRY approach. Instead, you need to inherit the User model from AbstractBaseUser and the UserBody from models.Model. Something like that:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=63, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class UserBody(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_bodies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False)
    blood_pressure = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False)
    blood_sugar = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False)
```

Serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('groups', 'user_permissions', )


class UserBodySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        user_body, created = UserBody.objects.update_or_create(user=user, **validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = UserBody
        fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```
class UserBodyView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

    def get(self):
        user_bodies = UserBody.objects.all()
        serializer = UserBodySerializer(user_bodies, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserBodySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Add to urlpatterns:

`path('api/v1/bodies/', UserBodyView.as_view(), name='user-bodies')`

Now you have the following endpoint:
/api/v1/bodies/

If you POST the following data:

```
{
        "height": 170,
        "weight": 70,
        "blood_pressure": 120,
        "blood_sugar": 20,
        "user": {
            "username": "dimitrionian",
            "email": "john_doe@gmail.com",
            "password": "qweqwe123"
    }
}
```

it will create a user instance and linked user_body instance. The serializer will return the following:

```
{
  "user": {
    "password": "qweqwe123",
    "last_login": null,
    "username": "dimitrionian",
    "email": "john_doe@gmail.com"
  },
  "height": 170,
  "weight": 70,
  "blood_pressure": 120,
  "blood_sugar": 20
}
```

This is a working and tested case. You can refine it further according to your needs. For example, set required permissions instead of applied AllowAny